# How to proxy URL call in Vue.js in production?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, proxy

In Dev, I have my local vue.js project and a dev server.  And I followed this guide:

http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html

to set up the `proxyTable` so that whenever I make a *REST* call to dev server using `Axios`, it will redirect to my dev server instead of the vue url.

When I deploy to prod, my vue build packages are deployed to S3 and my rest server is in *EBS*.  They are in different subdomains.  So my Vue needs to also set up a proxy for all *REST* calls.  However,  `vuejs&webpack` doesn't allow a proxyTable in the config file under `build` section.  What's the best way to handle this?

my config:

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: 'prod',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {
      '/api': {
       logLevel: 'info',
       target: 'http://myRestServer.com/...',
       changeOrigin: true,
       pathRewrite: {
         '^/api': '/'
       }
      }
    }, 
  },
 dev: {
   proxyTable: {
     '/api': {
      logLevel: 'info',
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3005',
       changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
         '^/api': '/'
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Vue.js runs in the browser. Unless you set up your own custom proxy service, you cannot route AJAX calls through a proxy.

Comment: You should define a dns for your API calls and proxy in your aws architecture

Answer (score -2):

May be you should use `devServer` instead. And for `build` I guess there is another name now.

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
   // your settings
  }
}
```

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: '<url>',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
      '/foo': {
        target: '<other_url>'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver)

Comment: This is for development environment, when Vue is serving files on localhost:8080.